# How can I check if an instance is in a dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, filter, pyspark, instance

I have an instance extracted from a dataframe df1 and I want to check if that instance is in another dataframe df2 in Pyspark. Is there way to face it?

For example:

Instance:

```
+------+------+------+
| Atr1 | Atr2 | Atr3 |
+------+------+------+
|  'A' |   2  |  'B' |
+------+------+------+
```

Dataframe:

```
+------+------+------+
| Atr1 | Atr2 | Atr3 |
+------+------+------+
|  'C' |   1  |  'B' |
+------+------+------+
|  'D' |   2  |  'A' |
+------+------+------+
|  'E' |   2  |  'C' |
+------+------+------+
|  'A' |   2  |  'B' |
+------+------+------+
```

This way, I want to get true because the instance is in the dataframe (4th row).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking for something like [`except`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#except-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-) ?

Comment: I am looking for something opposite to except. I mean, something that tells me if an instance is in a dataframe. I will edit my question for better understanding.

Comment: Did you try `instance.except(df).take(1).isEmpty`?

Answer (score 1):

`Pyspark` is not the right language to do this, but still:

First let's create our dataframes:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['A', 2, 'B']]), ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['C',1,'B'],['D',2,'A'],['E',2,'C'],['A',2,'B']]), ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3'])
```

you can use:

- `subtract`

  ```py
  df1.subtract(df2).count() == 0
  ```
- a `join`

  ```py
  df2.join(df1, ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3']).count() > 0
  ```
- a `filter`

  ```py
  df2.filter((df2.Atr1 == 'A') & (df2.Atr2 == 2) & (df2.Atr3 == 'B')).count() > 0
  ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can take the intersection of `df1` and `df2` and compare if the count of `df1` is equal to that of the intersection as follows:

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['A', 2, 'B']]), ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3'])
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['C',1,'B'],['D',2,'A'],['E',2,'C'],['A',2,'B']]), ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3'])
>>> df1.show() 
+----+----+----+
|Atr1|Atr2|Atr3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   2|   B|
+----+----+----+

>>> df2.show() 
+----+----+----+
|Atr1|Atr2|Atr3|
+----+----+----+
|   C|   1|   B|
|   D|   2|   A|
|   E|   2|   C|
|   A|   2|   B|
+----+----+----+

>>> df2.intersect(df1).count() == df1.count() 
True
>>>
```

For information on `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.intersect` check the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.intersect).